# BASH Variables with multiple commands and reentrant

Tags: bash, shell, command

I have a bash script that sources contents from another file.  The contents of the other file are commands I would like to execute and compare the return value.  Some of the commands are have multiple commands separated by either a semicolon (;) or by ampersands (&&) and I can't seem to make this work.  To work on this, I created some test scripts as shown:

test.conf is the file being sourced by test

Example-1 (this works), My output is 2 seconds in difference

test.conf

```
    CMD[1]="date"
```

test.sh

```
    . test.conf
    i=2
    echo "$(${CMD[$i]})"
    sleep 2
    echo "$(${CMD[$i]})"
```

Example-2 (this does not work)
test.conf (same script as above)

```
    CMD[1]="date;date"
```

Example-3 (tried this, it does not work either)
test.conf (same script as above)

```
    CMD[1]="date && date"
```

I don't want my variable, CMD, to be inside tick marks because then, the commands would be executed at time of invocation of the source and I see no way of re-evaluating the variable.

This script essentially calls CMD on pass-1 to check something, if on pass-1 I get a false reading, I do some work in the script to correct the false reading and re-execute & re-evaluate the output of CMD; pass-2.

Here is an example.  Here I'm checking to see if SSHD is running.  If it's not running when I evaluate CMD[1] on pass-1, I will start it and re-evaluate CMD[1] again.

test.conf

```
    CMD[1]=`pgrep -u root -d , sshd 1>/dev/null; echo $?`
```

So if I modify this for my test script, then test.conf becomes:
NOTE: Tick marks are not showing up but it's the key below the ~ mark on my keyboard.

```
    CMD[1]=`date;date` or `date && date`
```

My script looks like this (to handle the tick marks)

```
    . test.conf
    i=2
    echo "${CMD[$i]}"
    sleep 2
    echo "${CMD[$i]}"
```

I get the same date/time printed twice despite the 2 second delay.  As such, CMD is not getting re-evaluate.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - actually, I don't see the question. What exactly is are you trying to do, and where does it go wrong? Your "example", "test.conf CMD[1]=pgrep -u"... makes precious little sense - where is the "source file"? How are you parsing arguments - you're missing quotes as I see it?

Comment: This is a test script, not the actual.  Hence the reason the $i is still in there (cut -n- past) and this is lacking in clarity.  The CMD[x] where x = 0 ... 10 are test conditions that return either 1 or 0; mostly is the process running or not and similar to the pgrep example given above.  Along with CMD, I have a corresponding RESTART[x] that I call and after I call it, I re-evaluate the CMD[x] to see if the process restarted.  In other examples I am checking for presence of a log file.  I didn't want to bore the forum with these details but it would probably have been helpful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should never use backticks unless you need to be compatible with an old shell that doesn't support `$()` - *and only then*.

Secondly, I don't understand why you're setting `CMD[1]` but then calling `CMD[$i]` with `i` set to `2`.

Anyway, this is one way (and it's similar to part of Barry's answer):

```
CMD[1]='$(date;date)'    # no backticks (remember - they carry Lime disease)
eval echo "${CMD[1]}"    # or $i instead of 1
```

Comment: This also works.  I hadn't thought of this method.  Excellent, Thank You!

Comment: Do I understand right, that `CMD[1]` then holds already the outputs of the commands and not the commands itself?

Comment: @MattTT: No, it contains the commands because the assignment uses single quotes. The `eval` executes the commands. This question and answer pertain to a specific set of circumstances and aren't intended to be generally applicable. If you came here trying to solve a problem, there's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From the couple of lines of your question, I would have expected some approach like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    # munge $line
    if eval "$line"; then
        # success
    else
        # fail
    fi
done
```

Where you have backticks in the source, you'll have to escape them to avoid evaluating them too early. Also, backticks aren't the only way to evaluate code - there is `eval`, as shown above. Maybe it's `eval` that you were looking for?

For example, this line:

```
CMD[1]=`pgrep -u root -d , sshd 1>/dev/null; echo $?`
```

Ought probably look more like this:

```
CMD[1]='`pgrep -u root -d , sshd 1>/dev/null; echo $?`'
```

Comment: This works!  However, per my and your earlier comments (we agree) I don't want back ticks in there.  This script will not live on any other environments outside of Linux, I have no control over BASH and agree with your portability concern!